# Python Selenium in which iframe?

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

How am I able to check in which iFrame my driver is currently in? I got multiple functions entering in different iFrames - for a logic programme structure I'd like to implement a secure check in which iFrame the browser currently is focused / located, e.g. iFrame "banana" or "apple".

I selected those via:

```
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "example_xpath")))
```

Selection, etc. is perfectly working. For switching back to the "normal" default frame I'm using `driver.switch_to.default_content()`, though I don't always know in which I am, hence the question.

Comment: if you want to see on UI you can use javaScriptExecutor to highlight the frame. Or you can use getAttribute() to check the frame.

Comment: You're suggesting `print(driver.getAttribute())`?

Comment: element.get_attribute("attribute name")

Comment: You can compare if you can find an element when in an iframe.